# Android Studio - Getting the Scope Right

Tags: android, android-studio

Forgive me if I don't get all my terminology right here: I'm still an Android newbie. I am trying to create a pager app. The ReceiveAlert activity displays the content of an alert and plays a sound when it opens. After much struggling and googling I've got it to turn the volume up to max for playing the sound. Here is the onCreate code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_alert);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkPermission();
    }

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        taskingalert = bundle.getString(SmsReceiver.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView receivedAlert = findViewById(R.id.receivedAlert);
        receivedAlert.setText(taskingalert);


        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.thechain);
        final AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);            final int originalVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Then there is a button to stop the sound and move to the SendResponse activity. This is where I hit a problem. My code for that part is:

```
    public void respond(View view) {
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, originalVolume,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
    player.release();
    player.stop();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SendResponseActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, taskingalert);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

However Android Studio highlights mAudioManager, originalVolume, and player as problems and I can't make any sense of the suggested solutions. I assume they all have a scope that is limited to onCreate and doesn't apply to "respond".

I've tried putting the whole public void respond(View view) inside onCreate but that doesn't help and throws up other problems.

I've tried declaring MediaPlayer player, AudioManager mAudioManager and originalVolume before the onCreate. That gets rid of the red highlights in Android Studio but the app fails on test.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Variables do have a scope. In this case, you want to declare `mAudioManager`, `player` and `originalVolume` as *member variables*. Right now they are only *local variables* which only exist inside the `onCreate` method.

See this documentation for reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

In your case, it is sufficient to extract the variable declaration out of the `onCreate` method like this:

```
AudioManager mAudioManager;
MediaPlayer player;
int originalVolume

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_alert);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkPermission();
    }

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        taskingalert = bundle.getString(SmsReceiver.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView receivedAlert = findViewById(R.id.receivedAlert);
        receivedAlert.setText(taskingalert);


        player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.thechain);
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        originalVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Three things have changed:

- the variables are declared with their types at the top
- inside `onCreate` the variables get assigned with values (note: we don't specify the variable type there. This is only required for declaration.)
- the variables can't be final anymore since the are declared first and get a value later

Comment: That solved it. Thank you Alexander.
For anyone coming along here after, there was also an error in my second piece of code which may have been confusing my understanding of the problem. player.stop has to come before player.release.